# ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, flask-login, flask-oauthlib

Getting this error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Documents\Web Dev\Dinkum\backend\app.py", line 2, in
> <module>
>     from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth   File "E:\Documents\Web Dev\Dinkum\backend\dinkum\Lib\site-packages\flask_oauthlib\client.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     from werkzeug.urls import url_quote, url_decode, url_encode ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'
> (E:\Documents\Web
> Dev\Dinkum\backend\dinkum\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\urls.py). Did you
> mean: 'unquote'?
```

using
Flask-OAuthlib version : 0.9.6 
Flask version : 3.0.2
on app.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for, session, render_template
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=['backend/templates', 'frontend'], static_folder='backend/static')
```

Answer (score 0):

`url_quote` was removed in [werkzeug 3.0.0](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/2768). Which is why you are getting that error in `flask_oauthlib`.

flask_oauthlib last release was in 2020 and looks like it has been unmaintained. If you read [flask_oauthlib repository](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib) it says:

> **You SHOULD use https://github.com/lepture/authlib instead.**

---

You could either downgrade to Flask 2.3.x (and Werkzeug 2.3.x) or use `authlib` or any other oauthlib so you can use Flask 3.0.x